# What is the right word for a visitor visa to Japan? a Japanese visitor visa?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

How should I properly refer to a Temporary Visitor's Visa used to enter Japan as a visitor?

Is it:

> a Japanese visa

or:

> a visa to Japan

Comment: Wouldn't it be "Ticket to Japan" instead of *visa to Japan*? I think Japanese visa is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "Japanese visitor" could mean a visitor *from* Japan, so there could be some confusion arising from "a Japanese visitor visa" if you intend it to mean a visa for visitors *to* Japan.

Remember that Japan is the country, and "Japanese" describes anything relating to Japan or its language, culture, or people.

I don't know what such a visa is known as in the country of Japan, but I would say it should be referred to as:

> A Japan Visitor Visa

This is because you are a visitor to the *country of Japan*.

Certainly, if it were the UK we would call it "*a UK Visitor Visa*".